# Second jump in the air

Tags: android, iphone, box2d, andengine

I have player body. He has single jump. Namely when he jump, he has to wait touch ground for second jump.

```
 private ContactListener contactListener()
    {
        ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact)
            {
                 player.setJumping(false);


            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact)
            {

                        player.setJumping(true);




            }   
         };
         return contactListener;
    }
```

if there is a contact, he can jump. If not, he can't jump because he is in air. In that code, if his head touch any body, he can jump too. So here is the error. He has to jump only when his foot is touching. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the Adobe Integrated Runtime? or did you add the 'air' tag as part of the context of jumping?

Comment: second one! I'm using Andengine

Comment: Addition: How can we understand the body's touching side?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ID in the fixture data. If your player has two fixtures - the body and head, then you can assign tags to them and then check them, for example:

```
void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {       
    void* firstFixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetUserData();
    void* secondFixtureUserData = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetUserData();
    //check if fixtures was with the correct tags
    if ( (int)firstFixtureUserData == kPlayerBody || (int)secondFixtureUserData == kPlayerBody) { 
       if((int)firstFixtureUserData == kGround || (int)secondFixtureUserData == kGround) {
         player->jump();   
       }
   }   
}
```

I think this link will be useful: [jump ability](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumpability)